# Async each function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I'm trying to understand async `each(coll, iteratee, callback)` function to execute a function in parallel for each item of an array. From the async docs I understand that callback will be executed only once (when iteratee function will be executed for each item of the array).

And in the case of an error in the iteratee function, calling `callback('some error message')` will immediately call the callback function with error message.

Below is an example from the async docs for each function

## each(coll, iteratee, callback)

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

    // Perform operation on file here.
    console.log('Processing file ' + file);

    if( file.length > 32 ) {
      console.log('This file name is too long');
      callback('File name too long');
    } else {
      // Do work to process file here
      console.log('File processed');
      callback();
    }
}, function(err) {
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

What I'm not able to understand is, what does calling callback() without argument does, it looks very strange to me that we call callback() with no argument when there is no error in the iteratee function. What does calling `callback() or callback(null)` do in case of no errors.

Can't we just remove those `callback() or callback(null)`, when we actually mean to call the callback only once (when iteratee function is executed for all the elements of the array) rather than for each item of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does calling `callback() or callback(null)` do in case of no errors.

Calling `callback` with no arguments or with `null` signals to `async.each` that the `iteratee` function finished executing on that item (`file` in the case of the example). When all of the `iteratee` functions have called their respective `callback`, or one of them passes an error to it's callback, `async.each` will call the original `callback` function passed to it.

To elaborate on that a little, `async.js` is designed to handle asynchronous functions. The benefit (or issue, depending on how you look at it), of an asynchronous function is that there is no way to tell when it will finish executing. The way to deal with this is to pass the asynchronous function another function, a `callback`, to execute when it is finished. The asynchronous function could pass any errors it encounters, or any data it retrieves, to the original calling function through the `callback` function. For example, [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) passes the read file data, and any errors, through the `callback` function is it passed.

> Can't we just remove those `callback() or callback(null)`, when we actually mean to call the callback only once (when iteratee function is executed for all the elements of the array) rather than for each item of the array.

No, because `async.js` has to assume the `iteratee` function is asynchorous, and therefore, it has to wait for it to its `callback`. The `callback` passed to `async.each` is only called once.

The confusion may be caused by the variable names. An individual  `callback` function is only meant to be called once. The `callback` function passed to `async.each` is not the same `callback` passed to the `iteratee`. Each time `iteratee` is invoked with a value in `coll`, it is passed a new `callback` function. That call of `iteratee` is only supposed to call the passed `callback` once (`async` will throw an error otherwise). This allows `async` to track if a call to the `iteratee` function has called its `callback`, and wait for the rest to call their respective `callback`. Once all of the `callback` functions are called, `async.each` knows all of the asynchorous `iteratee` function calls have finished executing, and that it can call the original `callback` passed to it.

This is one of the difficult aspects of creating docs. They have to concise enough that a developer can get information from them quickly, and also include enough detail that they can explain the concept, or the function. It's a hard balance to achieve sometimes.

Comment: Thanks @hargasinski, I have one confusion , when we call callback() when there is no error in iteratee function, it looks like we are actually executing the callback function (third argument to async.each) for each element

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that can be confusing. You can rename the arguments something like `function(err, fileCallback)` and then call `fileCallback();` or `fileCallback('File name too long')` to make it a little clearer. In the example, the variables have the same name but represent different things.

Comment: Thanks mate, now I got it.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling callback with no arguments adds to a counter inside of the `.each` function. This counter, when full is the thing that actually calls your callback. Without that, it would never know when it completed.